# Set Pivot orientation to Landscape but what about the Height spacing

Tags: windows-phone-7

I set it with  SupportedOrientations="Landscape"  Orientation="Landscape"

I need to make the Header fontsize smaller and the adjust the height of the space or rectangle for all the the headers shorther so that there is more room for other controls to be placed in the Grid. What I need to do?

```
<controls:Pivot  Title="MY APPLICATION">

               < !--Pivot item 2-->
      <controls:PivotItem  Header="item1">
                <Grid>                    
                </Grid>
      </controls:PivotItem>

      <!--Pivot item 2-->
      <controls:PivotItem  Header="item2">
                <Grid>                    
                </Grid>
            </controls:PivotItem>

          < !--Pivot item 3-->
          <controls:PivotItem Header="item3">
               <Grid>  
               </Grid>

       </controls:PivotItem>


   </controls:Pivot>
```

Comment: You can probably just watch for the OrientationChanged event and reset your sizes in the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pivot.HeaderTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot.headertemplate%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to customize the header style according to your requirements.